# How can I save the state of a repeat control?

Tags: xpages

I have a repeat control generated based on a view.
I'd like to save the state of the repeat control when a user navigates to a document and returns.
I have tried the pager Save State control from ExtLib but that doesn't work.

Please advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont know if the `xe:pagerSaveState` should work with the repeat control. I always use the `xe:pagerSaveState` in combination with a View/DataView/ForumView. But when useing a reapeat i do something like this to get my state back:

When opening the 'EditYourDocument.xsp' XPage write the first element of the `xp:repeat` control to a scope like:

```
sessionScope.put('first',getComponent("repeat1").first);
context.redirectToPage("editDocument.xsp");
```

and add this code to your repteat:

```
first="#{javascript:return (sessionScope.first != null)?sessionScope.first:0;}">
```

when comming back to your view from any other site your view should display to the right page and data.

Comment: Excellent !!. Most Useful !!. Please submit as a Snippet.

Comment: This will complicate links to open documents (instead of simple url link you must use SSJS with redirect, what is POST instead of GET and that has additional performance consequences). I would suggest to put that code to repeat component events (rendered/loaded) so position is updated during paging (same view), and reset when coming back from document (page load).

Comment: As with most solutions the simple one is not always obvious. Great piece of code. I use it in the open button because I have to set several other things before doing a redirectToPage so that works great. Thanks 1/2 hour of cut and paste to each of my repeat views and I'm a happy camper.