# Using the StartKey on a viewDataSource

Tags: javascript, onclick, xpages, pager

When a user clicks on the link to open a document I set a sessionScope variable to the Key for that document. The StartKey property on the view dataSource is set to that sessionScope variable. All works well, but if I open a document on page one and return that document is at the top of the page and the back on the pager does not work. I don't see how to do an onClick event on the Pager at which point I could set the sessionScope to null and I expect the pager would work correctly ie go back to the first document in the view.
Is tehre a workaround to do an onClick event or ?? on the pager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the Pager Save State control from the extension library?  This control saves the state of the pager so when you leave and come back to a page the return will be at the same place you left off.  Saves having to manually keep track of all this.

Here is a related question and answer on the Pager Save State control.
[How can I save the state of a repeat control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084043/how-can-i-save-the-state-of-a-repeat-control)

Comment: The link to How can I save the state of a repeat control? contains a great fix for repeat controls. I could never get the PagerSveState to work in a repeat.

Comment: I'd advise reading the blog post I did on views http://www.intec.co.uk/understanding-xpages-views/. startKey doesn't move to the page containing that document. It subsets the view so the document you jump to is the first one in the contents for the view container. So as far as the view container is concerned, you are on page 1. It is no longer aware of any documents in the view prior to thos document.

Comment: @PaulStephenWithers That explains the experience that I had. I guess I can see some uses for that but when I looked for documentation on it the documentation really did not explain that it in fact created a subset of the data. What you said here needs to be in the documentation. When I read your post then look at the inline help in the all properties for First it makes sense. User documentation written by a techie rather than really helping.